# Background and text color when making a table

Tags: tables

I want to get the background colors of my table similar to this table, but not sure how to change the text to white and the background of the top column and rows to black. 
[image]

Ive used the following code so far:

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l c c c c c c c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{SeaGreen}\multicolumn{4}{|c}{\textbf{ESS3}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{ESS5}} \\
\rowcolor{SeaGreen}
    \textbf{Utfall} & \textbf{Kontroll} & \textbf{Behandling} & \textbf{Diff} & \textbf{Kontroll} &  \textbf{Behandling} & \textbf{Diff}&  \textbf{DiD}            \\

\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel A: No controls}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ [1ex]

\multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel B: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ [1ex]

\multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel C: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ [1ex]

\multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel D: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\ [1ex]
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ [1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

which yields the following output:

[image]

So I want the layout of the table to be the same as the table I already made, but I don't know how to change the background color and text color. I also want the white lines in the top part of the table to be removed but not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have any caption? And should it be on a black background?

Comment: Haven't included any caption yet. I want the upper part of the table to be black with white coloring and the lower part to be blue greyish with black text, if that answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with  `\colorbox` and `\rowcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\textbw}[1]{\bfseries\color{white}#1}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \colorbox{LightSteelBlue}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l*{7}{c}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{DarkSlateGrey}\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbw{ESS3}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbw{ESS5}} \\
    \rowcolor{DarkSlateGrey} \textbw{Utfall} & \textbw{Kontroll} & \textbw{Behandling} & \textbw{Diff} & \textbw{Kontroll} & \textbw{Behandling} & \textbw{Diff}& \textbw{DiD} \\

    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel A: No controls}}\\
    \textbf{Coef} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\
    \textbf{t-statistics} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\ [1ex]

    \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel B: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
    \textbf{Coef} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\
    \textbf{t-statistics} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\ [1ex]

    \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel C: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
    \textbf{Coef} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\
    \textbf{t-statistics} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\ [1ex]

    \multicolumn{8}{|l|}{\textbf{Panel D: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\ [1ex]
    \textbf{Coef} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\
    \textbf{t-statistics} & 0.075 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.091 \\ [1ex]
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility on how to achieve a white caption on a black background. I have also used the rules from the `booktabs` package.

The idea to use a colorbox in order to make the background of the rest of the table blue, is borrowed from [Bernard's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479335/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{mycaptionformat}{%
  \colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2\color{white}\bfseries#3}}
} 
\captionsetup[table]{format=mycaptionformat,font={color=white,bf},skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{my caption}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colorbox{LightSteelBlue}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X c c c c c c c}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{ESS3}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{ESS5}} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \textbf{Utfall} & \textbf{Kontroll} & \textbf{Behandling} & \textbf{Diff} & \textbf{Kontroll} &  \textbf{Behandling} & \textbf{Diff}&  \textbf{DiD}            \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: No controls}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ \addlinespace

\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ \addlinespace

\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Panel C: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ \addlinespace

\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Panel D: Controlling for individual characteristics}}\\ [1ex]
\textbf{Coef}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\
\textbf{t-statistics}   &   0.075  &    0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091   &   0.091 &   0.091   &   0.091 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```